# Count occurrences in a subset of a vector

Tags: c++

I tokenize a string into a vector containing seperate elements. Next, I want to count occurrences of a string in a subset of this vector. This worked when I want to simply use the whole vector with, as mentioned by the [guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/):

```
cout << std::count (tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), 20);
```

This will count all the occurrences of `20`.

Using an array it is possible to use a subset (from the guide):

```
int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};   // 8 elements
int mycount = std::count (myints, myints+8, 20);
```

The problem is that I want to use a subset of the *vector*, and I tried several things but they all do not work:

```
// Note: Here I count "NaN", which does not change the story.
std::count (tokens.begin(start[i]), tokens.end(end[i]), "NaN")        
std::count (tokens.begin() + start[i], tokens.end() + end[i], "NaN")
std::count (tokens + start[i], tokens + end[i], "NaN")
```

How to count occurrences in a subset of a vector?

Here is the context for a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string line = "1 1 1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN";
    std::vector<int> start = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> end = {1,2,3,4};    
    istringstream iss(line);
    vector<string> tokens;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         back_inserter<vector<string> >(tokens));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
       cout<<std::count(tokens.begin() + start[i], tokens.end() + end[i], "NaN");
     }
}

Error: Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You can't add a positive number to `tokens.end()`.  What range do you really want to search?

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. It should be `tokens.begin() + end[i]`.

Comment: (In the example where `start == end`, you count over empty ranges and will always get zero.)

Answer (score 2):

Adding integer to vector iterator works just like adding an integer to pointer. So you can do for instance:

```
cout << std::count (tokens.begin() + 5, tokens.begin() + 10, 20);
```

To count how many 20-s are there in tokens in positions with indexes `[5, 10)`.

Comment: In my example, you can see I do just that. Any idea why I get the error then?

Comment: You are adding to the end iterator. You should never do that. Instead add the size of the subarray to the value you add to the begin iterator like I do.

Comment: Such a simple mistake, yet holding me back for an hour. Thanks!